# Azure Functions log is always null

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I've created an Azure functions app targeting .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017. I'm using the simple **Hello, {name}** example that is automatically generated by the Azure Functions project template.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogDebug("A debug message");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

When I deploy it to Azure, run the function and then view the Invocation Details in Kudu, the log always has the value `null`.

[image: Kudu Invocation Details]

Hitting the Toggle Output button doesn't load the log. It hangs in *"Loading"* state indefinitely.

How do I view the log output for an Azure function?

Comment: I find the Kudu logs unreliable for Functions 2.0. It is best to configure App Insights and use view your logs through it (App Insights).

Comment: Agree. I have found it be very inconsistent. I am never sure when the logs are generated. I think Microsoft wants us to use Application Insights. But, this does not come free. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v2 functions in runtime 2.x, [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#changes-in-features-and-functionality) explains

> To improve monitoring, the WebJobs dashboard in the portal, which used the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` setting is replaced with Azure Application Insights, which uses the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` setting.

Like what you have seen, with AzureWebJobsDashboard setting, the log param is null and no log there. I am afraid the replaced with was enforced and **Dashboard has been deprecated**.

After creating Application Insight and add its `instrumentationkey` in Application settings, we could see the Monitor view is similar to Dashboard.

[image]

If we don't like it anyway, logs in kudu(`https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) are ready there(`D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\<functoinName>`).

Comment: This looks to me as a step taken by Microsoft to force developers to adopt Application Insights. I liked the fact that ILogger was being inserted into the Azure function. It provided basic logging functionality, without having to commit to Application Insights.  While , the Cloud simplifies scalability of hardware I am increasingly finding myself in a situation where I feel locked into a specific solution.